# 'There is no such a thing as a free lunch' in academic writing

Tags: expressions, british-english, academia

In the context of an academic publication in *British* English, I'm tempted to paraphrase the expression 
*"There is no such a thing as a free lunch".*

Does it sound too informal and, if so, are there more formal alternatives? And, is it too American for a British paper?

Comment: Cite Robert Heinlein, The Moon is a Harsh Mistress

Comment: I'm familiar with 'You get nothing for nothing', which has a reasonable number of hits on Google.

Answer (score 4):

The most-recognized form of the quote is "[There ain't no such thing as a free lunch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_ain%27t_no_such_thing_as_a_free_lunch)", from *The Moon is a Harsh Mistress* by Robert Heinlein. If you're going to use it you should probably quote it correctly, and cite the source. This version is of course even more informal than the one you write, but if you explicitly state it is a quote then that shouldn't be an issue, even in an academic paper.

The phrase is going to be about as well-recognized in the UK as in the US.

You can of course paraphrase the saying into a more formal form. Perhaps "Even seemingly cost-free meals always come with disadvantages."

Comment: That's only if you want to actually quote Heinlein. The phrase is older than that!

Comment: I liked the paraphrased one, I think I'll use that one. Thnx.